# Using docker image on CI/CD pipeline with CircleCI

Tags: typescript, docker, deployment, continuous-integration, circleci

I need to build docker image on CI/CD pipeline with using CircleCI but I have no idea how to do this :/
It must work in this way, that when i merge pull request on git, then my pipeline launch docker image build and run test within this docker, here is my circleci config file:

config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@3.0.0
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    executor:
      name: node/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install-packages
      - run:
          command: npm run test
workflows:
  build-and-test:
    jobs:
      - build-and-test
```

right now, when i launch this config on merge my pulls, then my pipeline is failed because of databse network bad connection, and this is normal because i have no connection to db, so, I want to build docker image and then in docker container run circle ci pipeline,

here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose: 
      - '8080'
    command: npm run start
```

can someone tell me how to do this?, how to build docker image and launch test within in on circleCI pipeline?

Thanks for any help!